# Run query based on POST values with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows a user to select a county from a dropdown menu, My form is then posted to my functions.php page where I've been using IF statements to run my queries.

```
if ($_POST['dropdown1'] == 'option 1' && $_POST['dropdown 2'] == 'option 4' && $_POST['county'] == 'cheshire' ) {
    // RUN QUERY 
}
```

My problem is however I can't realistically use IF statements for every county in every possible scenario as there will be thousands of options, has anybody got a better idea of how I can do this?

---

```
if ($_POST['vehicleType'] == 'hgv' && $_POST['coverageRegion'] == 'national' ) {        

            $customkey = 'vehicleType'; 
            $customvalue = $_POST['vehicleType']; 

            $customkey1 = 'coverageRegion'; 
            $customvalue1 = $_POST['coverageRegion']; 

            $customkey2 = 'locationType'; 
            $customvalue2 = $_POST['locationType']; $args = array('orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'order', 'order' => 'ASC',

            'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => $customkey,
                'value' => $customvalue,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => $customkey1,
                'value' => $customvalue1,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => $customkey2,
                'value' => $customvalue2,
                'compare' => '='
            )
            ) // end of array
            ); //end of if

            $query = new WP_Query( $args);





            // The Loop
                $i = 0; $i = -1;

while ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    $i++;
    $query->the_post();
    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() )
    {
        echo "<div class='clearfix card-prod ".($i==0?'first':'')."'><div class='top-dets'><span class='card-title'>";
        echo the_title();
        echo "</span>";


    // Network query 
        $network_value = get_post_custom_values('srchnetwork');
        foreach ( $network_value as $key => $value ) {
        echo '<span class="srch-val-">'. $value . '</span>'; }// Pricing Query
        $pricing_value = get_post_custom_values('srchpricing');
        foreach ( $pricing_value as $key => $value ) {
        echo '<span class="srch-val-1">'. $value . '</span>'; }

    // Setup Query
        $setup_value = get_post_custom_values('srchsetupfee');
        foreach ( $setup_value as $key => $value ) {
        echo '<span class="srch-val-2">'. $value . '</span>'; }

    // Services Query
        $services_value = get_post_custom_values('srchservices');
        foreach ( $services_value as $key => $value ) {
        echo '<span class="srch-val-3">'. $value . '</span></div>'; }

    // Big Card Query
        $bigcard_value = get_post_custom_values('bigcard');
        foreach ( $bigcard_value as $key => $value ) {
             echo '<a href="/" class="cardclick"><img src="/wp-content/themes/CAFC/images/cards/'. $value . '" alt="'; }
     echo the_title() . '" /></a>';


    echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/CAFC/images/top-choice.jpg" alt="Top Choice" class="topchoice">';
echo the_excerpt()."</div>";   }
}

       }
```

Comment: whats the query you are running ?

Comment: What do you want to do inside the if ? Could you explain what query you would like to execute ?

Comment: It's on a wordpress site @adrien, I want filter all posts based on certain meta values in the custom fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your code in this way so you don't have to deal with every possible option.

```
global $wpdb;

$postKeys = array('vehicleType', 'coverageRegion', 'locationType');

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array()
);

foreach ($postKeys as $key) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => $key,
        'value' => $wpdb->escape($_POST[$key]),
        'compare' => '='
    );
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Is that all I'd need @ilanco? Im new to PHP so im not too sure what I need to keep and remove in regards to using your above code and my old code...

Comment: And how does the above know whats been posted via the form??

Comment: I don't recommend using anybody's code unless you understand what it does, even if it works. I think you are missing some basic knowledge about control structures in php (for, while, foreach), please read up on them here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php